# C++ equivalent for simple Java polymorphism

Tags: java, c++, polymorphism

I'm struggling with a seemingly simple task in C++.  I'm trying to achieve basic OOP polymorphism.

Consider this Java example:

```
interface Bob
{
   void foo();
}

class ActualBob implements Bob
{
   void foo()
   {
      /* I like foo things */
   }
}

class Jane
{
    Bob bob;
}
```

Jane can have any Bob, easypeasy:

```
Jane jane = new Jane();
jane.bob = new ActualBob();
jane.bob.foo(); // actualbob things
```

Now, in C++ this seems somewhat more involved....
What do I have to type to get the above behaviour?

In other words, I would like to have member variables of an abstract base class, but would like to do actual-implementation things with them.

```
class Bob
{
public:
   virtual void foo() = 0;
}

class ActualBob : public Bob
{
public:
    void foo(){/* I like foo things */}
}

class Jane
{
public:
    Bob bob;
}
```

Taking shortcuts here, but I'd like to do, in C++:

```
jane.bob.foo(); // does ActualBob things
```

Also, can I have a `std::vector<Bob>` which contains `ActualBob` instances?

Comment: You need to use pointers or references for polymorphism to work.

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) has some documentation on virtual functions, but in all fairness, a good book might be a good idea.

Comment: you need to use point and virtual function.

Comment: @spinalwrap - knowing C gets you nowhere near to knowing C++. No need for a 3000 pages book, if you know a language or two a basic 1000 page book would do it ;)

Comment: @spinalwrap It's honestly a complex and sometimes subtle language.  If you can get comfortable with some of the core concepts first (types, modifiers, keywords, templates, polymorphism, operator overloading, smart pointers, standard template library), you'll probably be okay.  Scott Meyers' books might also help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use pointers, smart pointers, like this:

```
class Bob
{
public:
   virtual void foo() = 0;
}

class ActualBob : public Bob
{
public:
    void foo() override {/* I like foo things */}
}

class Jane
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Bob> bob;
}
```

> Taking shortcuts here, but I'd like to do, in C++:
>
> ```
> jane.bob.foo(); // does ActualBob things
> ```

You can do this:

```
jane.bob->foo(); // does ActualBob things, if `bob` is a pointer to ActualBob
```

> Also, can I have a `std::vector<Bob>` which contains `ActualBob` instances?

Yes, with some modifications, you can have a `std::vector<Bob*>` (but you must free memory on your own) or, better, some smart pointers, like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bob>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would be fine if `Bob` were non-polymorphic:

```
class Jane
{
public:
    Bob bob;
};
```

However, trying to store a polymorphich object in `bob` would lead to *object slicing*, which drops polymorphism. In order to preserve it, use a pointer or a reference to `Bob`.

Depending on the ownership of `Bob` you could use a different kind of pointer, or even a reference. For example, if `Bob` is allocated dynamically, and could be shared among multiple instances of `Jane`, using `std::shared_ptr<Bob>` would be appropriate:

```
class Jane
{
public:
    Jane(Bob* bPtr) : bob(bPtr) {}
    std::shared_ptr<Bob> bob;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You nearly have it. The problem is that it seems in Java that you don't have to use anything in order to create a polymorphic object, while actually in Java all that variables are references. Java references are C++ pointers with less capabilities.

In C++, when you type `Bob bob;`, you're actually creating an object of the precise type on the left. When you use a pointer instead, then at the right you can have a **Bob** object (which would be impossible in this case, since the class **Bob** has a pure virtual method), or any other subclass.

So, in your code:

```
class Jane
{
public:
    Jane()
        { bob = new ActualBob(); }

    Bob * bob;
}
```

We have, however, run into a different, dangerous scenario without warning. Java has a garbage collector, basically meaning that any object which is not referenced is deleted. This is not done automatically in C++, so we have to do it manually, using the `delete` operator. Or maybe a smart pointer in this case: they behave in C++ doing the deletion of the object automatically. We have `std::unique_ptr<>` available, doing exactly that. There are indeed other scenarios, such as copying **Jane** objects, which are somewhat managed by a smart pointer. So instead of talking about [rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) (destructors, copy constructors, operator assignment, and family), let's use one of them:

```
class Jane
{
public:
    Jane()
        { bob.reset( new ActualBob() ); }

    unique_ptr<Bob> bob;
}
```

The `unique_ptr<>` smart pointer captures the use of `->` (technically, it has the arrow operator overloaded), so its use is syntactically familiar to the use of a regular pointer. Now:

```
Jane jane = new Jane();
jane.bob->foo();
```

> Also, can I have a `std::vector<Bob>` which contains ActualBob
>   instances?

Sure, but have to change your code in the same way as above: you would have to use `std::vector<Bob *>`, and free the objects pointed by the members yourself. Or, you could use again a smart pointer, as in: `std::vector<unique_ptr<Bob>>`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is 2016 today, time to forget about `std::auto_ptr` :-)